# PyCharm Professional: How to use an interpreter, running in a docker container on a second machine

Tags: python, docker, remote, pycharm

Setup:

- 1st machine (client): Windows with PyCharm Professional installed. Laptop, no GPU.
- 2nd machine (server): Ubuntu with docker installed. Workstation with GPU.
- 3rd machine (docker container): running on 2nd machine

I'm writing code on my laptop (client), which has no GPU. However, I need to test the code on a GPU. Therefore, I'd like to configure PyCharm (on my laptop), so that I can run and debug my code inside a docker container, which is being run on the server. I already tried reading the official PyCharm documentation (e.g. [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html)), however, I was not able to solve the problem.

I would be really grateful, if someone could help me out with this problem or point me in the right direction, as I have been struggeling with it for quite some time now.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you connect from client side to server side with docker? Try a simple `docker system info` or `docker run hello-world` to test. If it works then 99% is done.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, I don't fully understand your request yet. What do you exactly mean by 
"from client side to server side with docker"?
I guess you mean in PyCharm?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. On the client (i.e. the windows machine) I can run docker without any problems in the command line. However, that is of course only locally on the client. Now that I come to think about it, my question might have been formulated sloppy. I want the code to be executed on the server, inside a docker container. I rephrased the question a little to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not natively supported by PyCharm, unfortunately. In the meantime, it is possible to configure such a setup with some extra clicks by using the deployment feature, see the following instruction https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33489